# How to properly log out in Nuxt 3 / Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

The problem i am having is that when i log out of one tab, other tabs are still working. The token clears out but it can still access the website on other tabs.

I used this code to check for changes in the storage and then logout of other tabs too:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {  
        if (!store.state.user.token) {
            return redirect('/sign-in');
        }
      });
```

But it doesn't work. this code was put in `mounted` in one of the layouts in Vue JS/Nuxt 3. Kindly help?

Comment: What is the thing that doesn't work? Is the user token kept alive in the other tabs? How do you clean up your storage?

Comment: @Aritz logout doesn't work properly. if i log out then it should log out of other tabs too. or atleast i should not be able to navigate on other tabs, if i try to navigate then it should redirect to sign in page. the token does change to ```null``` if i sign out. and yes it clears out token of other tabs.

Comment: Have you checked what cookie values are being stored?

Comment: @Aritz token is stored in the storage.. i don't know how it relates to cookies??

Comment: I don't know about Nuxt, but I mean that if you still are able to load content with the token cleared out from local storage, maybe the Nust framework is picking it from somewhere else... Or you need to clear out other things in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:-

1. Import the auth module from [@nuxtjs/auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/)
2. Create a function called logout that uses the [auth.logout()](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/#logoutargs) method.
3. Bind the logout function to an event, such as a button click.
4. When the event is triggered, the logout function will be called and the user will be logged out.

Nuxt3/Vue JS Simple Example:-

> JS part

```
import { auth } from '@nuxtjs/auth';

export default {
  methods: {
    logout() {
      await auth.logout(); // clear the user's token from local storage and redirect the user to the login page
    },
  },
};
```

> HTML part

```
<button @click="logout">Logout</button>
```